# Is "Esas cestas son hechas de mano" correct?

Tags: traducción

I want to say "These baskets are made by hand". Is it correct to say:

> Esas cestas son hechas de mano.

Comment: "Esas cestas son hechas _a_ mano?" also "son artesanales?".

Comment: "baskets" are also "canastas"

Comment: Thank you very much. If you want you can make this into an answer and i'll vote it up and accept it.

Comment: It appears you are translating a statement, and not a question (as the question form in English would be "Are these baskets made by hand?").  If I was incorrect to remove the question marks, please feel free to reverse my edit.

Comment: It was meant to be a statement, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct translation would be: "*Estas cestas son hechas **a** mano*"

And "*Estas cestas **están** hechas a mano*" would also be perfectly valid.

The masculine "*Estos cestos*" is also correct.

*Canastas* is not often used, at least in Spain, unless you are talking about basketball...

Comment: In Murcia, Spain, I came across *canasta* frequently referring to a type of flexible container somewhere between a bucket and a basket (now plastic but presumably once basketwork) used frequently by builders, fishermen, and so forth as a general purpose container. I don't know if this use of the word - which obviously comes from the "basket" meaning - is common elsewhere. As there is, to my knowledge, no word for this object in English, my family now uses the word *canasta* in English too...

Answer (score 3):

"Hechas **de** mano" would mean something like "handen", as "hechas de madera" would mean "wooden". Usually, "las cestas están hechas de mimbre" (wicker).

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely say "Esas cestas **están** hechas a mano", instead of "**son**". It sounds much more natural to me.

Comment: But wouldn't estan imply more of a temporary condition?